# How to fetch TOTP code using the secret key in C++

Tags: c++, totp

I am trying to build a algo trading bot. I need to connect with my broker which requires me to enter the totp code generated using the secret key. I have the secret key with me, but I am not able to generate the totp code from that in c++.

I have tried using the oath library https://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/liboath-api/liboath-oath.h.html, openssl library for direct HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, in every case the totp generated is different from what is shown in google authenticator, and it does not work.

This is the openssl code i have used -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

std::string generateTOTP(const std::string& secret, unsigned long timeStep, int digits) {
    const unsigned char* key = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(secret.c_str());
    int keyLen = secret.length();

    // Get the current Unix time
    unsigned long current_time = time(nullptr) / timeStep;

    // Convert the time to big-endian
    current_time = htobe64(current_time);

    // Create the data to be hashed (current time)
    unsigned char data[8];
    memcpy(data, &current_time, sizeof(current_time));

    // Calculate the HMAC-SHA1 hash
    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int hashLen;
    HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, keyLen, data, sizeof(data), hash, &hashLen);

    // Calculate the offset
    int offset = hash[hashLen - 1] & 0xf;

    // Calculate the 4 bytes OTP
    int binary = ((hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24) |
                 ((hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16) |
                 ((hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8) |
                 (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

    int otp = binary % static_cast<int>(std::pow(10, digits));

    // Convert the OTP to a string with leading zeros if needed
    return std::to_string(otp);
} 
int main() {
    const std::string secret_key = "###################";
    const int digits = 6; // Number of OTP digits

    std::string totp = generateTOTP(secret_key, 30, digits);
    while (totp.length() < digits) {
        totp = "0" + totp;
    }
    std::cout << "Generated TOTP: " << totp << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the oath code i have tried. Oath code is also giving different output as compared to google authenticator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <oath.h>

int main() {
    const char* secret_key = "####################"; // Replace with your actual secret key
    char otp[6];
    int otp_len = sizeof(otp);

    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto current_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();
    unsigned long time_step = 30; // TOTP time step (usually 30 seconds)

    if (oath_totp_generate2(
        secret_key, 
        strlen(secret_key), 
        current_time, 
        OATH_TOTP_DEFAULT_TIME_STEP_SIZE, 
        OATH_TOTP_DEFAULT_START_TIME, 
        otp_len,
        OATH_TOTP_HMAC_SHA256, 
        otp) == 0) {
        // otp[otp_len] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the OTP
        std::cout << "Generated TOTP: " << otp << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error generating TOTP." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not possible to help you without further information. Did you verify that you are using the same seed and algorithm as the google authenticator you're trying to emulate?

Comment: @Botje I have added the code, can you see if it makes it any clearer. I have used HMAC-SHA1 which is used by google authenticator, i am not sure about the seed value.

Comment: What are we supposed to compare it to? Does your code give the same output as the oath library, at least?

Comment: @Botje oath library uses HMAC-SHA256, it gives different output as compared to oath library. But even the oath library code is not giving the same output as google authenticator.

Comment: You should start with identifying the exact algorithm and secret value google auth uses before trying to do anything else

Comment: @Botje are their no available libraries who have done this for c++, like totp library exists in python ?

Comment: Probably. But "TOTP" is not sufficient to identify the exact library or configuration you are looking for. Identify the exact algorhtm and parameters first.

Comment: If you replace `OATH_TOTP_HMAC_SHA256` by 0 in the call to `oath_totp_generate2` then your hand-written code produces the same result as liboath. (because HMAC-SHA1 is the default) So, back to the original question: what parameters/algorithm is google auth using, if not the TOTP RFC?

Comment: I have this link for reference https://medium.com/concerning-pharo/the-code-behind-google-authenticator-9c59c606a572 still not sure why am I doing wrong @Botje

Comment: Once again, that post exactly describes the TOTP algorithm that both you and liboath successfully implement. Did you notice the bit about base32-encoding the secret key? How did you extract the key from google auth and how did you plug it into your code?